# Nested SELECT statements and reading in nested JSON file in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

The discussed problem has been solved partly in here:
[Read in nested JSON file in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73343686/read-in-nested-json-file-in-sql-server/73344697#73344697)

but now the JSON file was extended with more objects of different format.

```
Declare @json nvarchar(max)
SELECT @json =
N'{
  "Model": {
    "Energy-X/A": {
      "x": 1,
      "y": 2,
      "z": 3
    },
    "Energy-X/B": {
      "x": 4,
      "y": 5,
      "z": 6
    }
    },
  "Energy": 
  {
    "Energy-X/A": [
      [
        100.123456, null
      ],
      [
        101.123456, null
      ]
    ],
    "Energy-X/B": [
      [
        102.123456, null
      ],
      [
        103.123456, null
      ]
    ]
  }
}'

select * from openjson(@json, '$.Model')
with (x [int] '$."Energy-X/A".x',
      y [int] '$."Energy-X/A".y',
      z [int] '$."Energy-X/A".z',
      x [int] '$."Energy-X/B".x',
      y [int] '$."Energy-X/B".y',
      z [int] '$."Energy-X/B".z'
      );

select commaDelimited.* from openjson (@json) 
with (energyXA nvarchar(max) '$.Energy."Energy-X/A"' as json,
      energyXB nvarchar(max) '$.Energy."Energy-X/B"' as json
     ) as energy
    cross apply (
    select
    (select string_agg(isnull(value, 'null'), ',') from openjson(energyXA, '$[0]')),
    (select string_agg(isnull(value, 'null'), ',') from openjson(energyXB, '$[0]'))
    union all
    select
    (select string_agg(isnull(value, 'null'), ',') from openjson(energyXA, '$[1]')),
    (select string_agg(isnull(value, 'null'), ',') from openjson(energyXB, '$[1]'))
)   commaDelimited ([Energy-X/A], [Energy-X/B]);
```

The solution works and the values can be extracted but now I want to combine both SELECT statements into one query and construct a correlated subquery. The columns should appear when "Energy-X/A" and Energy-X/B" match like:

| Energy-X/A | Energy-X/A | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.123456, null | 101.123456, null | 1 | 2 | 3 |

| Energy-X/B | Energy-X/B | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102.123456, null | 103.123456, null | 4 | 5 | 6 |

or also better output would be to sum up the values of `Energy-X/A` and `Energy-X/B` in one, separate column (using a delimiter such as semicolon):

| Energy-X/A | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.123456, null ; 101.123456, null | 1 | 2 | 3 |

| Energy-X/B | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102.123456, null ; 103.123456, null | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I am grateful for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by _... The columns with the corresponding values_? Do you mean that `"Model"` matches `"Energy-X/A"`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Zhorov. I just edited the answer with an examplary result.

Comment: Sure, I just formatted the output. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you changed your expected results significantly, I've completely re-written your query.

Start by unpivoting the A and B values into separate rows using a `(values)` table and `json_query`.

Then read those columns using `openjson`.

In the case of `Energy` you need two levels of aggregation also, in order to get your second expected result.

```sql
select
  commaDelimited.*,
  model.*
from (values
    (json_query(@json, '$.Model.BCS'),  json_query(@json, '$.Energy."Energy-X/A"')),
    (json_query(@json, '$.Model.BCSA'), json_query(@json, '$.Energy."Energy-X/B"'))
) j(model, energy)
outer apply openjson(j.model)
  with (
    x int,
    y int,
    z int
  ) model
outer apply (
    select
      Energy = string_agg(c.Energy, ' ; ')
    from openjson(j.energy) energy
    cross apply (
        select
          Energy = string_agg(isnull(Xinner.value, 'null'), ', ')
        from openjson(energy.value) Xinner
    ) c
) commaDelimited;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1685882d3d0888065ec034a5a994365b)

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for the elegant solution. Unfortunately, while you posted your answer I was editing my question so that the expected result has changed a bit

Comment: See latest edit

Comment: Perfect! I have not thought about the combined usage of "outer" and "cross apply", thank you very much!

Comment: `outer` is just a left-join, as opposed to `cross` which is an inner join. Depends on your data whether you need it

Comment: Unfortunately, I still encounter a minor problem because the `Energy-X/A` and `Energy-X/B` should be separated. Now, all values are summarized in the column `Energy`. The reason why I want to have them separated is because I want to join the columns by including the strings "X/A" and "X/B" with another table having the same specified string.

Comment: You could just add it as a literal string inside the `values` unpivot https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=611b44fc6f829b0f46c47d24c5dcf1df

Comment: Wow, you are faster than I can think about this problem. :) Last follow-up question: If I have another table with the column names `X/A` and `X/B` and I would like to join the column `energyId` by looking up the values inside the columns, e.g., `Energy-X/A` and `Energy-X/B` by parsing them into `X/A` and `X/B`. So there should a partial string match given. Probably, I need to use the string()-functions in order to parse and format the values `Energy-X/A` and `Energy-X/B` inside the `energyId` column, right?

Comment: You could use `openjson` or `json_query` with a dynamic path based on concatenating it together with the rest of the path. Something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=359922182b88b7c2fb7472da697967b7. Any further questions please create a new post for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me alot! I'll try to solve the rest on my own. If I should not get it done I will create a new post!